# New Node isnt re-balancing properly

Tags: infinispan

I am running an embedded cache cluster in kubernetes as a 3 instance Statefulset with persistence using SIFS. Cache is persisted to a PVC per instance.

The cluster starts up fine, log entries are showing re-balancing happening between the 3 members and everything is good. If I push traffic through the cluster I can see log entries for SIFS creating, compacting and destroying files etc. The problem comes when one of the nodes is removed and re-added. I can see the cluster acknowledge the loss of the node and then over time it returning to the cluster as it restarts. At that point it looks to me like there is a re-balance missing or incomplete on the new NODE because I then get loads and loads of errors in the logs of the remaining 2 NODES, usually stuff like this

```
ISPN000136: Error executing command RemoveCommand on Cache
```

I also notice that the compacting process on the new node no longer executes so there is a buildup of files on that node
I am assuming I am missing something small but fundamental which will force the new node to fully re-balance when it joins but I cant work out what that might be and the documentation isnt proving of much use.

I am using 14.0.11.FINAL with config

```
MODE: REPL_SYNC
AWAIT-INIT-STATE: false
FETCH-IN-MEMORY-STATE: true
PERSISTENCE: enabled
PERSISTENCE
    PURGE-ON-STARTUP: false
    SHARED: false
    PRELOAD: false
```

These are log entries found in the node that is removed and then rejoins, I have included lines showing that there no apparent compaction and deletion going on after the node rejoins

```
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,455] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t26] - Node if-test-cache-service-1-64847 joining cache demo001 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,458] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.Compactor] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t2] - Compacting to 0 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,459] [INFO] [org.infinispan.LIFECYCLE] [] [jgroups-5,if-test-cache-service-1-64847] - [Context=demo001] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [if-test-cache-service-0-23900, if-test-cache-service-2-59262, if-test-cache-service-1-64847], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 13 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,459] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl] [] [jgroups-11,if-test-cache-service-1-64847] - Updating local topology for cache demo001: CacheTopology{id=12, phase=NO_REBALANCE, rebalanceId=4, currentCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (2)[if-test-cache-service-0-23900: 131+125, if-test-cache-service-2-59262: 125+131]}, pendingCH=null, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[if-test-cache-service-0-23900, if-test-cache-service-2-59262], persistentUUIDs=[592e4780-e9b6-4ffd-8a8f-82523add533c, f696c460-9ac4-4510-aac7-4a4f6685a61e]} MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,461] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t27] - Updating local topology for cache demo001: CacheTopology{id=13, phase=READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, rebalanceId=5, currentCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (2)[if-test-cache-service-0-23900: 131+125, if-test-cache-service-2-59262: 125+131]}, pendingCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (3)[if-test-cache-service-0-23900: 87+169, if-test-cache-service-2-59262: 86+170, if-test-cache-service-1-64847: 83+173]}, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[if-test-cache-service-0-23900, if-test-cache-service-2-59262, if-test-cache-service-1-64847], persistentUUIDs=[592e4780-e9b6-4ffd-8a8f-82523add533c, f696c460-9ac4-4510-aac7-4a4f6685a61e, 262a8f0a-cca8-4433-8cd2-cf1eab6efab3]} MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,461] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t27] - Starting local rebalance for cache demo001, topology = CacheTopology{id=13, phase=READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, rebalanceId=5, currentCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (2)[if-test-cache-service-0-23900: 131+125, if-test-cache-service-2-59262: 125+131]}, pendingCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (3)[if-test-cache-service-0-23900: 87+169, if-test-cache-service-2-59262: 86+170, if-test-cache-service-1-64847: 83+173]}, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[if-test-cache-service-0-23900, if-test-cache-service-2-59262, if-test-cache-service-1-64847], persistentUUIDs=[592e4780-e9b6-4ffd-8a8f-82523add533c, f696c460-9ac4-4510-aac7-4a4f6685a61e, 262a8f0a-cca8-4433-8cd2-cf1eab6efab3]} MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,462] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t27] - Adding inbound state transfer for segments {0-255} MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,462] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.commons.util.ServiceFinder] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - No service impls found: TargetMigrator MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,463] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - Started cache demo001 on if-test-cache-service-1-64847 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,464] [INFO] [org.infinispan.LIFECYCLE] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t27] - [Context=demo001] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [if-test-cache-service-0-23900, if-test-cache-service-2-59262, if-test-cache-service-1-64847], topology id 13 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,466] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager] [] [main] - Started cache manager if-test-cache-service-1-64847 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,467] [INFO] [com.iconsolutions.ipf.core.platform.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider] [] [main] - Cache model specified timeout of PT17088H min, max of 100 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,485] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.1) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,491] [INFO] [com.iconsolutions.ipf.core.platform.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider] [] [main] - Cache demo001 specified timeout of PT10M min, max of 100000 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,492] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.statetransfer.InboundTransferTask] [] [jgroups-5,if-test-cache-service-1-64847] - Finished receiving state for segments {0-4 13-50 74-98 104-110 152-170 191-198 222-244 250-255} MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,503] [INFO] [com.iconsolutions.ipf.core.platform.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider] [] [main] - Cache demo001 specified timeout of PT10M min, max of 100000 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,541] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.0) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,541] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.statetransfer.InboundTransferTask] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t27] - Finished receiving state for segments {5-12 51-73 99-103 111-151 171-190 199-221 245-249} MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,541] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t27] - Finished receiving of segments for cache demo001 for topology 13. MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,544] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t30] - Updating local topology for cache demo001: CacheTopology{id=14, phase=READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, rebalanceId=5, currentCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (2)[if-test-cache-service-0-23900: 131+125, if-test-cache-service-2-59262: 125+131]}, pendingCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (3)[if-test-cache-service-0-23900: 87+169, if-test-cache-service-2-59262: 86+170, if-test-cache-service-1-64847: 83+173]}, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[if-test-cache-service-0-23900, if-test-cache-service-2-59262, if-test-cache-service-1-64847], persistentUUIDs=[592e4780-e9b6-4ffd-8a8f-82523add533c, f696c460-9ac4-4510-aac7-4a4f6685a61e, 262a8f0a-cca8-4433-8cd2-cf1eab6efab3]} MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,547] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t2] - Updating local topology for cache demo001: CacheTopology{id=15, phase=READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, rebalanceId=5, currentCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (2)[if-test-cache-service-0-23900: 131+125, if-test-cache-service-2-59262: 125+131]}, pendingCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (3)[if-test-cache-service-0-23900: 87+169, if-test-cache-service-2-59262: 86+170, if-test-cache-service-1-64847: 83+173]}, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[if-test-cache-service-0-23900, if-test-cache-service-2-59262, if-test-cache-service-1-64847], persistentUUIDs=[592e4780-e9b6-4ffd-8a8f-82523add533c, f696c460-9ac4-4510-aac7-4a4f6685a61e, 262a8f0a-cca8-4433-8cd2-cf1eab6efab3]} MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,549] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t1] - Updating local topology for cache demo001: CacheTopology{id=16, phase=NO_REBALANCE, rebalanceId=5, currentCH=ReplicatedConsistentHash{ns = 256, owners = (3)[if-test-cache-service-0-23900: 87+169, if-test-cache-service-2-59262: 86+170, if-test-cache-service-1-64847: 83+173]}, pendingCH=null, unionCH=null, actualMembers=[if-test-cache-service-0-23900, if-test-cache-service-2-59262, if-test-cache-service-1-64847], persistentUUIDs=[592e4780-e9b6-4ffd-8a8f-82523add533c, f696c460-9ac4-4510-aac7-4a4f6685a61e, 262a8f0a-cca8-4433-8cd2-cf1eab6efab3]} MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:54,549] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateConsumerImpl] [] [non-blocking-thread--p2-t1] - Removing no longer owned entries for cache demo001 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:41:58,375] [INFO] [com.iconsolutions.ipf.core.platform.cache.infinispan.InfinispanCacheProvider] [] [main] - Cache model specified timeout of PT17088H min, max of 100 MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:42:12,700] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.1) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:19,820] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t2] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.2) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:19,832] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t2] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.2) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:20,957] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.3) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:20,961] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.3) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:21,754] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.4) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:21,759] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.4) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:22,798] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.5) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:22,816] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.5) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:23,836] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.6) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:23,849] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.6) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:24,897] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.7) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:24,898] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.7) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:26,050] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t2] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.8) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:26,069] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t2] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.8) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:26,956] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.9) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:26,958] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.9) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:28,189] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t2] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.10) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:28,195] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.10) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:29,170] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t2] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.11) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:29,179] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t3] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.11) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:30,312] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t2] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.12) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:30,323] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t2] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.12) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:31,113] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.13) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:31,123] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.13) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:32,192] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.14) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:32,216] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.14) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:32,216] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t3] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.14) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:33,090] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t3] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.15) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:33,093] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t3] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.15) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:34,127] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.16) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:34,134] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.16) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:35,113] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.17) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:35,117] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.17) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:36,090] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.18) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:36,101] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.18) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:37,163] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t3] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.19) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:37,166] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.19) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:38,139] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t1] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.20) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:38,145] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t4] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.20) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:40,894] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t3] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.21) MDC: {}
[2023-07-11 06:43:43,045] [DEBUG] [org.infinispan.persistence.sifs.FileProvider] [] [blocking-thread--p3-t3] - openChannel(/cachepaxi/demo001/data/ispn12.21) MDC: {}
```

Comment: Better open a ticket in [JIRA](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN) or bring the discussion in [Zulip](https://infinispan.zulipchat.com/). In any case, we need the configuration (`infinispan.xml`) and the full log files from all the nodes. Thanks.

Comment: thanks to the Zulip folk, the issue was a missing cachManager.stop(). Makes all the difference because state is persisted when the node is brought down.